# How do I animate different sprites with different buttons? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've been trying to animate this sprite using different onClick button triggers. Only one of the buttons works in fiddle. But on my file version the other buttons works but they only work once and it does not reset. (As in some buttons play, but only in a certain order and then I can't press on them again)  I assumed the removeClass would remove it after a certain amount of time where it would return to the original state so that I can click another button and it would repeat the animation from the start.

HTML

```
   <div class="bannerimg" div id="bannerimg"></div>
   <div id="sunbutton" class="sunbutton"></div>
   <div id="waterbutton" class="waterbutton"></div>
   <div id="foodbutton" class="foodbutton"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#sunbutton').click(function() 
    {
    $('.bannerimg').addClass('suncheck');
        setTimeout(function() 
            { $(this).removeClass('suncheck'); }
        , 1000);
    });

$('#waterbutton').click(function() 
    {
    $('.bannerimg').addClass('watercheck');
        setTimeout(function() 
            { $(this).removeClass('watercheck'); }
        , 2000);
    });

$('#foodbutton').click(function() 
    {
    $('.bannerimg').addClass('foodcheck');
        setTimeout(function() 
            { $(this).removeClass('foodcheck'); }
        , 1);
    });
```

CSS

```
.bannerimg {
    background-image: url(http://www.elainemcheung.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sprite.png);
    width: 669px;
    height: 560px;
}

.suncheck {
    animation: sun steps(7) 1s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: sun steps(7) 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: sun steps(7) 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes sun {
    0% {background-position: 0 0; }
    100% {background-position: -4683px 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sun {
    0% {background-position: 0 0; }
    100% {background-position: -4683px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes sun {
    0% {background-position: 0 0; }
    100% {background-position: -4683px 0;}
}

.foodcheck {
    animation: food 3s steps(12) 0.15s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: food 3s steps(12) 0.15s infinite;
    -moz-animation: food 3s steps(12) 0.15s infinite;
}

@keyframes food {
    0% {background-position: 0 -560; }
    100% {background-position: -8028px -560;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes food {
    0% {background-position: 0 -560; }
    100% {background-position: -8028px -560;}
}
@-moz-keyframes food {
    0% {background-position: 0 -560; }
    100% {background-position: -8028px -560;}
}

.watercheck {
    animation: water steps(15) 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: water steps(15) 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: water steps(15) 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes water {
    0% {background-position: 0 -1120; }
    100% {background-position: -10035px -1120;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes water {
    0% {background-position: 0 -1120; }
    100% {background-position: -10035px -1120;}
}
@-moz-keyframes water {
    0% {background-position: 0 -1120; }
    100% {background-position: -10035px -1120;}
}

.sunbutton {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    font-size: .9em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sunbutton:after {
    top: 0px;
    left: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 125px;
    border: 1px solid #894603;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(247,147,30,1) 0%,rgba(216,123,25,1) 44%,rgba(168,94,20,1) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    font-family: 'Duru Sans', sans-serif;
    content: "SUN ME";
}

.waterbutton {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    font-size: .9em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.waterbutton:after {
    top: 0px;
    left: 275px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 125px;
    border: 1px solid #63072D;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(212,20,90,1) 0%,rgba(181,21,86,1) 44%,rgba(140,16,66,1) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    font-family: 'Duru Sans', sans-serif;
    content: "WATER ME";
}

.foodbutton {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    font-size: .9em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.foodbutton:after {
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 125px;
    border: 1px solid #321559;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(131,94, 170,1) 0%,rgba(100,76,132,1) 44%,rgba(69,48,96,1) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    font-family: 'Duru Sans', sans-serif;
    content: "FEED ME";
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/22Skk/

Comment: Is the extra "div" in your html meant to be there `<div class="bannerimg" div id="bannerimg"></div>` ?

Comment: Remove white space within the function.

Answer (score 1):

It's because $(this) in setTimeout points to window, not to your button.
Change your js to this:

```
var bannerImg = $( '.bannerimg' );
$( '#sunbutton' ).click( function() {
  bannerImg.addClass( 'suncheck' );
  setTimeout( function() { bannerImg.removeClass( 'suncheck' ); }
    , 1000 );
} );

$( '#waterbutton' ).click( function() {
  bannerImg.addClass( 'watercheck' );
  setTimeout( function() { bannerImg.removeClass( 'watercheck' ); }
    , 2000 );
} );

$( '#foodbutton' ).click( function() {
  bannerImg.addClass( 'foodcheck' );
  setTimeout( function() { bannerImg.removeClass( 'foodcheck' ); }
    , 1000 );
} );
```

I've tried this on local computer and it works fine.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D7rD6/